# PREROUTING interfaces SSL MITM

Tags: tls, iptables

I'm trying to make SSL MITM attack but do not really understand how to configure my interfaces to preroute traffic.

I have a laptop, connected to a PC via Ethernet, the PC is connected to the rest of the network vie Ethernet as well.

The PC is running Linux. It has a bridge lets call it mimtbr, and I connected to the bridge the laptop's eth - `leth`, and the PC's network - `pceth`.

Then I configure iptables:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i leth -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i leth -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

And on `localhost` I have a running `sslsplit` listening ports `8080` and `8443`.

And `PREROUTING` doesn't work. The laptop can connect to any web-site directly.

Can someone suggest me what I'm doing wrong, please.

Comment: try `-i pceth`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work out how to make it with bridges and solved it another way.

Using DHCP daemon I assign to the laptop an IP and redirect all the traffic via PC. In this case I just configure proper NAT and `PREROUTING` works smooth then.

Comment: I realize that this question is old. However, it makes sense that it didn't work with bridging. Bridging effectively uses those two interfaces like an Ethernet switch at layer 2. Your IPtables rules are operating at layer 3 and above, and will have no effect on the passing of packets across the bridge.